# Upload a flash based banner as easy as image

Tags: 7, forms, files

Is there a way to add a field that can process a Flash file just like an image and print that file for what it is, just like an image, in a node or whatever?

Comment: I do not know how to fix this, so I skipped it, and I am trying to fix it some other way, using views and an usual file field.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module for your requirement.

Comment: Will that support just chosing a file without having to add it to a text field?

Comment: How would I do this then?

Comment: no, that textbox is browse box with browse button.If you want only browse button then you need to use hook_form_alter for the Media Module

Comment: Ah, I now have a browwe button in my text field. But it wont let me upload a swf/flv file?